# Is it possible to setup http routes without annotations in Spring Boot?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc

Consider an example from javalin.io framework, where you can do something like this in runtime:

```
Javalin app = Javalin.create().start(7000 /*port*/);
app.post("/my/route", ctx -> ctx.result("Hello World"))
```

and it will create an appropriate http route with this handler.
Can I do something like this with Spring Boot/MVC?

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.2.3.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/web.html#webmvc-fn

Comment: @JBNizet This is exactly what I'm looking for! You could write it as an answer and I will select it.